# Is it necessary to sanitize $_SESSION[''] data or is it paranoid?

Tags: php

The input originated from user input, but it's already been sanitized.

Better to be safe than sorry or just over-kill?

Comment: where is the session data stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$_SESSION` is basically the equivalent of your code making a text file for every user (identifying different users by magic, for explanation's sake), and storing some variables in that text file. Except for **your code** or something else on **your server**, nothing should be modifying the `$_SESSION`. So, if you make a habit of sanitizing everything before storing it in `$_SESSION`, you don't have to sanitize it again.